# Sorting in Primefaces 11 - expression changed

Tags: primefaces

So I'm upgrading to Primefaces 11.0.0. I see that for static columns the regex have changed to only accept the case sortBy="#{car.name}". For dynamic columns its e.g #{car[column.property]}. So its much more strict. I have previosly used sortBy="#{treetab.row.cellMap[column.id]}". So this is not working as the regex does not handle it. How should the sortBy expression be?

Comment: I think you want to report this at https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues

Answer (score 0):

You can read about it in this issue: https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/7607

And this commit which fixes that issue:
https://github.com/Rapster/primefaces/commit/6711515e233ed75b08cc09e7f12c30162b250884

Comment: So I have to use the case sortBy="#{car.name}"?